# I've uninstalled Xcode and many apps were uninstalled too

Tags: xcode

I've uninstalled Xcode 4 to reinstall it:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

...and now I don't have `Terminal.app` and the `Activity Monitor.app` and I don't know what else apps were uninstalled.

I'm running Lion 10.7.2. Is there a way to recover this apps?

Answer (score 4):

Both of those tools should be in your `/Applications/Utilities` folder. They should not be removed when uninstalling Xcode using that tool.

If they are no longer there, you can copy them from another machine running 10.7.2. I would make sure to pull them from another machine running the same version of the OS. This is only if you know you are missing a particular application.

The better route, if these applications are truly missing, would be to reinstall the OS, since as noted in the comment below, there could be many other items missing as well. With Lion, there is a new recovery tool built in. Make sure you backup your data first though.

To recover, just hold down Command + R when rebooting. [More information is available on Apples website](http://www.apple.com/macosx/recovery/).

Comment: He wrote he didn't know exactly what else has been deleted. Therefore I would not recommend dragging only those two applications back, but to reinstall the OS, making sure there's nothing else missing.

Comment: I completely agree with this, if he can verify they are gone. The uninstall-devtools script shouldn't remove any of these applications. Will update my answer to make it more clear.